# what is the Advantage of DLR in C# 4?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

What is the main Advantage of DLR in C#4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great link [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article651-net-40-faq-part-1--the-dlr.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in most articles where DLR is introduced to those who have never heard of it.  [Here](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2007/04/microsoft-reveals-dynamic-language-runtime-for-net.ars), for example.  To repeat or type a new answer here would be redundant.